# Visual indication of selected list item

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to jQuery mobile and even newer to knockout.js. Now, I am to develop a website for mobile devices using asp.net mvc4 framework.

Most of the pages in this website will have two sections, one narrow left section which will drive the page, and the center section which is the result section.

Now, in the left narrow section, there is going to be a list of Farms and the user can select one or more farms.

The challenge is to display the selected list items with some visual indication that they have been selected. So, the entire list will be there and the ones the user has selected will be displayed with (selected) or something similar with the actual text of the list-item.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `.ui-btn-active` class to any button widget to apply an `active` state to the button.

Here is the basic idea:

```
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <a class="ui-btn-active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
```

And to update all the button widgets in a `listview` you can do something like this:

```
$('ul').find('a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fg2TX/2/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will try that. Please have a look at the issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358846/knockout-js-jquery-mobile-conflict-node-was-not-found-bug)  that I am having using jQuery mobile and knockout.js on the same page. Sorry to bother you like this but I have no idea how to fix this issue or whom I should notify as I need to use both libraries. You seem to be experienced in jquery mobile so I just let you know with hope that probably you'd have an answer.

Comment: Edited your code on jsfiddle so now the text "Selected" is being appended to each of the clicked list-item. I need to display that "Selected" text at the end of each list-item where the right arrow is (in place of the arrow or below the arrow) in a different color and style (probably). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Edited some more to reflect what I am trying to achieve. The problem currently is, the rounded corner and other pretty styles disappears if I use ui-btn-active class. Ideally, I'd like to change the theme dynamically so the selected list-items have a different style, but $(this).parent().attr("data-theme", "a") does not work. Googled and did not find a decent solution to change the theme dynamically or change the style of a list-item to indicate that it is active. Please note that more than one list-items can be selected at the same time. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Debarupa/czqXm/

Comment: Sorry @DebarupaDe, I'm not familiar with Knockout JS. Just wrap the `Selected` text in a `<span>` tag with a class, then create a CSS class that positions the element to the right.