# Knockout.js, jQuery mobile conflict {Node was not found} - bug?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am using jQuery mobile and Knockout.js to test the first example on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html but nothing is displayed and error console of FireFox reveals this error:

Timestamp: 9/10/2012 1:13:16 PM
Error: NotFoundError: Node was not found
Source File: http:///kotest/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js
Line: 46

Note that this is the latest knockout-2.1.0.js downloaded today.

The code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
     <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <h4>People</h4>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
           <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      ko.applyBindings({
        people: [
                { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
                { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
                { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Dentiste' }
            ]
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I should mention that it works as expected if references to the jQuery mobile js files are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
You can try the jQuery mobile pageinit function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
      ko.applyBindings({
        people: [
                { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
                { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
                { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Dentiste' }
            ]
      });

    });    
    </script>
```

include a div Tag with the data-role="page" binding from jquery mobile:

```
<div data-role="page" >
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
           <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but that did not fix it. Put ko at the top and put the ko code inside document ready function. Getting the same error but the only difference is, The table heading titles are now displayed.

Comment: thx for your feedback..I found the solution in the jquery mobile document. It is not the ready event, it is the document pageinit event for jquery mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I've updated my answer. That should go now, or check the answer from Himango.

Comment: Including <div data-role="page" > fixed the issue. Didn't even have to edit the javascript code although I'm binding to the pageinit event as well as suggested by Judah Himango per the jquery mobile documentation. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your document is not in the ready state. Since you're using jQuery mobile, you'll want to listen for the pageinit event,  then apply your KO bindings in that:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    // Use KO here
});
```

Note that Daniel's answer suggests to use document.ready, however, [that doesn't work](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) in the jQuery mobile bits where page contents are loaded asynchronously via AJAX. Instead, you must use pageinit event.